# Jaas tomcat "no security manager"

Tags: java, tomcat, authorization, jaas, securitymanager

I am trying to write a loginmodule for jaas authentication/authorization. I thought I would try an example first. I am running tomcat 7 with the following example
http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/jaas-authentication-in-tomcat-example

I get the following: "no security manager" in the myeclipse console when I try to login. In fact I place a break point to try to see if the login module is even being used.

I seem to possibly not have the security manager running. Questions:
 1. I tried to run it with the -security in the launch arguments but still I get the same message.
2. how do you run the security manager with a tomcat application.

Does anyone know or have a full example of how to apply authorization? I also noticed in this example that he is not saving the subject in a session variable. How would tomcat recognize what subject is trying to access a resource in a following request? ...

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if MyEclipse uses the same views as Eclipse, but try this:

1. Open "Servers" view
2. Double click the server name in the list.
3. At the bottom you can find an option called "Enable Security".